# What does the word 「いっこめ」mean?

Tags: words, colloquial-language, video-games

I came across the word from the sentences.

> **いっこめ**はサービスだポ。もっていくポ。

Does it possible come from a combination of 「一個」, which means a piece or an object, and 「め」, which means somewhat or quite?

Comment: It's 一個目. "The first one is for free, take it!"

Comment: What does the ポ at the end mean?

Comment: I guess it comes from a video game or an anime. I reckon ポ is uttered by robot-like character.

Comment: @maritsm the 「ポ」is usually said by a group of characters in a video game Dragon Quest series spin-off.